# How can I connect my WSL docker container to a local instance of Mariadb/MySql on Windows?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm a bit lost on how to set up routing from within a WSL docker container back to things on windows. I should note that I am deliberately not using Docker Desktop.

So here's the scenario:

I have an installation of MariaDB installed on my Windows 10 machine with the standard IP and port 127.0.01:3306.

I have an updated instance Ubuntu installed via WSL 2 from the windows store Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to be exact.

On Ubuntu, I have a docker installed and working(ish) with a running Centos container.

I need my PHP project to be able to communicate with the windows installation of MariaDB.
My confusion is that in my docker container(centos), I can set my /etc/hosts file to point the domain local_db to -> 127.0.0.1 but I believe that makes it only try to communicate within the docker image its self (where no database instance exists) when I access that domain. Furthermore, on Unbuntu I can do the same thing but I can't be sure if it's actually going to talk to the right port or not on windows or if it's just contained inside of Ubuntu unable to get out.

So then the question is, how do I not only reach/route out of my docker container to WSL but beyond that into Windows as well?

Some of my research was suggesting that I somehow need to use 0.0.0.0 to "bind to anything/everything" but simply trying to use that instead of localhost, as I'm sure you experts know, is proving not to be sufficient.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: I followed this guide to setup WSL:
https://dev.to/bowmanjd/install-docker-on-windows-wsl-without-docker-desktop-34m9?utm_source=dormosheio&utm_campaign=dormosheio#launch-script-for-raw-dockerd-endraw-
I don't know if the way I mount things into WSL is relevant or not at all though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of installing Docker within Ubuntu within WSL 2, you probably will have better results installing Docker Desktop directly on Windows. It still uses WSL 2 to run your containers, but it integrates better with Windows.

Specifically, Docker Desktop adds a hostname to the internal DNS resolver named `host.docker.internal` that resolves to the host computer.

---

You can probably also do this without Docker Desktop, but it is pretty annoying since it needs to be done again every time you start a container and the information changes when you reboot. Here is what you would have to do (I have not actually tested this, but in theory it should work):

1. Make sure you are using Docker 20.04 or newer.
2. In your Ubuntu instance, determine the internal IP address of Windows - run `route -n` and find the "Gateway" address. *Note that this address may change when you reboot your computer.*
3. Start your Docker containers with the following two additional arguments: `--add-host=host.docker.internal:<THE_GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS_YOU_FOUND_BEFORE> --net=host`. This will give your container the ability to use `host.docker.internal` to connect to Windows services.

(Note that you cannot use `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` as printed in many tutorials because that will point to Ubuntu in WSL, not to Windows.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. Maybe I can come up with some boot up script or something that can derive the information for me

Comment: ```
HOST_DOCKER_INTERNAL=$(route -n | grep -m 1 "UG" | awk '{print $2}')
echo HOST_DOCKER_INTERNAL: $HOST_DOCKER_INTERNAL
```